# Is there any correlation between numbers and sensory experience?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics

Numbers exist, that is clear to me, but is there any logical correlation between numbers and sensory experience? This question came while I was reading Einstein's comments on Bertrand Russell's theory of knowledge. Einstein says that it is clear that the series of integers is a creation of the human spirit and that there is no way we could crystallize this concept (of integers) through sensory experience. Why is that? I can feel if one or two things are touching me and I can see if there are one or two sheep in front of me. Is he talking about the number without any kind of object attached to it (one is different than one sheep)? 
Can this be explained even though I didn't read Russell's theory of knowledge?

Comment: We have to consider numbers as [Abstarct objects](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/abstract-objects/) themselves, and not two different sheeps, i.e. two individuals physical objects.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synesthesia

Comment: Maybe relevant : Anna Sfard, [Thinking as Communicating : Human Development the Growth of Discourses and Mathematizing](https://books.google.it/books?id=cqwx8aDfUuQC&printsec=frontcover), Cambridge UP (2008) and Heike Wiese, [Numbers Language and the Human Mind](https://books.google.it/books?id=Reea4B-NG90C&printsec=frontcover), Cambridge UP (2003) and Stanislas Dehaene, [The Number Sense: How the Mind Creates Mathematics](https://books.google.it/books?id=2zkS7ylIDlsC&printsec=frontcover), Oxford UP (1999).

Comment: How about being asked to take a various numbers of steps forward and back, with forward being designated positive and steps backward being nnegative? That would be a sensory experience. Wouldn't it "crystallize" the concept of integers for you?